# 2-item support calculation

Tags: r, probability, analysis

I need to compute 2-item support. As for the given data I have a matrix of conditional probabilities and the probabilities to put an item as the first item in the basket are following:

```
c("Hammer", "Nails", "Screws", "Screwdriver", "Wrench", "Level", "Drill", "Brush")
p<-c(0.02, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.05, 0.01, 0.02, 0.3)
```

so for 1-item support I did simple

```
t(CondProbs)%*%p
```

Can you give me hints for the followings?

by saying 2-item support I mean Calculating the chance of appearance P(X, Y ) for each pair of products. I have 1-item support:

```
sup1=c(0.15,0.49,0.64,0.57,0.19,0.09,0.12,0.58)
```

with the help of this I need 2-item support. I found one example, but what I know for sure, I should calculate it without using **for** function.

```
>for (j in 1:n){
+ if(sup1[j]>=supthresh){
+ for (k in j:n){
+ if (sup1[k]>=supthresh){
+ sup2[j,k]<-data[,j]%*%data[,k]
+ sup2[k,j]<-sup2[j,k] } } } }
> sup2<-sup2/nobs
> sup2
```

p.s. **supthresh** is a threshold for rules here we have `supthresh<-0.2`

Comment: maybe you could give a little more context.  I'm not in your field, and I don't have any idea what "2-item confidence" and "2-item lift" are.  I could presumably google them, (e.g. [here](https://www.solver.com/xlminer/help/association-rules)) but it would be easier if you told us.

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the reply, I will make some changes to the question

Comment: @BenBolker is it okay now?

Comment: seems somewhat better. (what is `supthresh` in your code snippet ... ???)

Comment: thresholds for rules `supthresh<-0.2` @BenBolker

Comment: dear @BenBolker, unfortunately i reached the limit of giving new questions, so only hope is you. Maybe you have some ideas for it?